# Does Azure NotificationOutcomeState.Completed mean the notification was received on the phone?

Tags: android, ios, azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

The Per Message Telemetry feature of Azure Notification Hub gives back a number of outcome states. What exactly does 'Completed' mean? The documentation says it means "Message processing has completed", but I don't know what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the [documentation on NotificationOutcomeState enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.notificationhubs.notificationoutcomestate) is a bit confusing:

> Completed: NotificationOutcome when the notification sent has been
>   recevied

In this case it means "received by the corresponding push notification service". So, if it's an iOS device, it would be "received by APNS".

After that, those services do not provide information about what happens to the accepted notification. The only way of knowing whether it was received on the phone or the user tapped on it would be to write custom code and store that state somewhere. (Or use one of the analytics solutions.)

Comment: Thanks. What analytic solutions give this ability?

Comment: I'm not an expert on those, you might need to try a couple of different ones. [Azure Mobile Engagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/mobile-engagement/) would be a good place to start from. Also remember that some mobile OSes might not expose certain events in their SDKs or there could be differences between what events Android and iOS give you a way to react to. So it's possible that even by using an analytics solution you would not get as much information as you'd like because it's just not exposed to any kinds of developers at all.